# How to make double lines border in CSS, each line in different color, without using background image?

Tags: css

How to make a double line border in CSS, each line in a different color without using `background-image`?

For example like this:

[image]

Code:

```
<h2> heading 2 </h2>
<p> paragraph text </p>

<h2> heading 2 </h2>
<p> paragraph text </p>
```

*Note: I'm not considering IE 8, 7, 6*

Comment: No i don't want to use image and `<hr>`

Comment: Ah, *without* a background image, I misread.

Comment: Do I remember correctly that in CSS3 you can set multiple borders? No?

Comment: @crashdow - How? Do you know any example?

Comment: See [here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I just found the way on google search and it's working good for me.

```
h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 red;}
```

Source : http://www.cvwdesign.com/txp/article/425/useful-tip-for-creating-double-borders-with-css3

**Edit :** I found another way to achieve multiple border using  CSS 2.1 pseudo-elements

Support: Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+, Chrome 4+, Opera 10+, IE8+

http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/

Answer (score 16):

You can do it with the :after pseudo element:

http://jsfiddle.net/aCgAA/

```
h2 {
padding: 5px 0;
border-bottom: solid 3px pink;
font-weight: bold;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 8px;
}

h2:after {
content: '';
border-bottom: solid 3px blue;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
bottom: -6px;
left: 0;
}
```

This degrades gracefully to a single line if the :after selector is not available.

Answer (score 7):

it is possible in CSS3 very easily. try with the following code

```
h2
{
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #ff0000; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #ff0000; /* Safari and Chrome */
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Hi arif thanks for the answer. I've already found this method and given answer of my question.

Comment: this eats away 2px from the next immediate html element :(

Answer (score 6):

```
border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 red;
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a way to do this without an additional element.

There's `outline`, but it doesn't allow a `outline-bottom` rule: An outline can only  be identical on all four sides.

The `:after` pseudo-class will allow the adding of text content only, no elements.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/8g7Kv/) how to do it with an additional `hr`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you try add a `<span>` between `<h2>` and `<p>` with the following css:

```
span {
height:0;
border-top:blue;
border-bottom:#ff0000;
line-height:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what ADW said, in fact I'll edit his fiddle to help explain the difference.

In your description you explicitly described **h2** *followed by* **p** should have the double border in between.

ADW's solution is good enough, only when there is only one p after the h2, but if there is another p, it will have a strange red line between the paragraphs. That's why we should only select the p which is immediately following a h2.

CSS selector for **p immediately following h2** is **h2 + p**

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/gR4qy/42/

```
h2 { border-bottom: solid pink;}
h2 + p { border-top: solid blue; }
```

This is nothing new. It's CSS 2.1! http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Unfortunately there's nothing I can think of to get rid of the blue border if the p is missing. You're on your own there :S

Sorry I have to get 50 points before I can comment and I dont know how to get points so I pposted this as a new answer :S

Answer (score 0):

```
h2 { border-bottom: solid blue;}
p { border-top: solid red; }
```

Will get you close, then play around with margins and padding until things line up.

http://jsfiddle.net/gR4qy/

Comment: no i don't need in this way. I only want to give border to `<h2>` because sometime a `<h3>` can come just after `<h2>`

Answer (score 0):

Just take away the margins between the items so that their borders fit right against one another.  Here's a complete example -- size of the borders made large so it's easy to see.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>

<style type="text/css">
h2 { border-bottom: 10px solid blue; margin-bottom: 0; }
p { border-top: 10px solid green; margin-top: 0; }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<h2>Hiya</h2>
<p>La la la</p>

<h2>Hiya</h2>
<p>La la la</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

also see **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/nUkb7/1/)**

```
h2 {
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
p {
    border-top: 3px solid blue;
    margin-top: -20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: What if there are two paragraphs?

Comment: I just used the markup as provided in the question. If there are more then you would use the appropriate selectors for this

Answer (score 0):

Just had to do this, we're implementing a two-tone shadow in our app. Being an mobile app we want to avoid <kbd>box-shadow</kbd> (performance) so an even simpler solution using <kbd>:after</kbd>, where its absolutely positioned based on its parent is:

```css
 :after{
   content: '';
   display: block;
   height:0;
   border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
   border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -3px;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
```