# Is it possible to create double borders in CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to rely on CSS to create a double border for a navigation menu bar where there is a double border on top and a double border at the bottom. I'd also like for the two lines to have 1px shadows to create an embedded look.

[image]

How do I do this using CSS?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753351/how-to-make-double-lines-border-in-css-each-line-in-different-color-without-u

Comment: @JitendraVyas That's kind of different because the two lines are on top of each other. I want the two lines to have a space in between like in the image and I'm not sure how to make a padding/margin between a shadow and a border.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:after` property for this. write like this:

**CSS**

```
div{
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    border-top:1px solid green;
    border-bottom:1px solid green;
    margin:10px;
}
div:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:-3px;
    bottom:-3px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    border-top:1px solid green;
    border-bottom:1px solid green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ECFBR/8/

Comment: Thanks! This works great. I was wondering whether it's possible to add shadows to all the borders? I have applied box-shadows to both div elements (div and div:after) but only the bottom two borders show the shadow.

Comment: you can also achieve this with double border property also check this http://jsfiddle.net/ECFBR/9/

Comment: The double border works as well but the problem is that it doesn't allow you to adjust the width between the double border (like the first border line and the second border line). And if you try and apply a box-shadow, it only applies to the bottom line as well.

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with?

```
border-top: 3px #000 double;
border-bottom: 3px #000 double;
```

Comment: @F.Calderan I've tried this but is it possible to determine the height between the two lines and create 1px shadows for all of the lines?

Comment: @Daphne, You can use a nested elements to emulate the effect then, for padding.