# How to create double border which is not touching to edges in pure css?

Tags: css

In a navigation design I need to give border like this. I know [how to create double border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753351/how-to-make-double-lines-border-in-css-each-line-in-different-color-without-u) but don't how to create border which has some gap on top and bottom.

[image]

I know it can be done using an images but curious to know if it's possible to make in CSS only

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it can easily be done using just CSS.

## [demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/3780993)

**HTML**:

```
<ul class='navigation'>
    <li><a href='#'>nav item</a></li>
    <!-- as many navigation items as you would like -->
    <li><a href='#'>nav item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.navigation { padding: 0; list-style: none; }
.navigation li {
    float: left;
    padding: .35em 0;
    border-top: solid 2px #e4e4e3;
    border-bottom: solid 3px #94a10f;
    background: linear-gradient(#fafafa, #e5e5e5);
}
.navigation a {
    display: block;
    padding: .5em;
    border-left: solid 1px #fff;
    border-right: solid 1px #a4a4e3;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
.navigation li:last-child a { border-right: none; }
```

---

Alternatively, **if you don't want to have a non-clickable area at the top and bottom**, you could try it the other way:

## [demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/3781034)

**CSS**:

```
.navigation {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: .35em 0;
    border-top: solid 2px #e4e4e3;
    border-bottom: solid 3px #94a10f;
    background: linear-gradient(#fafafa, #e5e5e5);
    list-style: none;
}
.navigation li {
    float: left;
    border-left: solid 1px #fff;
    border-right: solid 1px #a4a4e3;
}
.navigation a {
    display: block;
    padding: .5em;
    margin: -.35em 0;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation li:first-child { border-left: none; }
.navigation li:last-child { border-right: none; }
```

---

A third way to do this, also **extending the clickable area to the borders as well** would be to use pseudo-elements on the links to get the lateral borders.

## [demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/3781063)

**CSS**:

```
.navigation { margin-top: 7em; list-style: none; }
.navigation li {
    float: left;
    background: linear-gradient(#fafafa, #e5e5e5);
}
.navigation a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: .85em;
    border-top: solid 2px #e4e4e3;
    border-bottom: solid 3px #94a10f;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation a:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: .35em; bottom: .35em; left: 0;
    border-right: solid 1px #fff;
    border-left: solid 1px #a4a4e3;
    content: '';
}
.navigation li:first-child a:before { border: none; }
```

Comment: I think the challenge here is to have the `<a>`-s go full height, so when you mouse over and highlight them they don't have the gap on the top and bottom - http://dabblet.com/gist/3781025

Comment: Just add a `:hover` on `li` if I don't misunderstanding because when you mouse over the `a`, you mouse over the `li` too.

Comment: @Ana +1 Very good. Thanks for answer and for double border tip using first and last child. In my case I wanted give all space to `<a>` though

Comment: I've also added a third method now - this one extends the clickable area to the borders as well.

Comment: @Ana Do you use Sass and Compass?

Comment: Just to know. By the way all the solution you gave are good but making problem in css dropdown which I wanted to use in project http://jsfiddle.net/csswizardry/Zj4eb/

But you gave the answer to my question very well. Thanks